# Power spectral density and windowed RMS measurements

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis

What is the relationship between the RMS deviation $X_{RMS}(T)$ of a stationary random signal $X(t)$ over a time window $T$, i.e.
$$
X^2_{RMS}(T) = E\left[\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tdt\left(X(t)-\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T dt' X(t')\right)^2\right]
$$
and the power spectral density $S(f)\equiv |\tilde{X}(f)|^2$, i.e. the fourier transform of the correlation function $E\left[X(0)X(t)\right]$?
More specifically, can this expectation value be expressed as a weighted integral over the PSD?

My expectation is that as the time window $T$ is shortened, then the components $S(f)$ where $f T \ll 1 $ do not contribute much to $X_{RMS}(T)$, or in other words that the windowing "filters" the PSD. I confirmed for the simple case of an exponential autocorrelation function $\sim e^{-\frac{|t-t'|}{\tau}}$ that indeed $X_{RMS}(T)$ begins to decrease once $T \approx \tau$, but want to know if there are simple rules for reasoning about $X_{RMS}(T)$ for a random signal with some arbitrary PSD.

For instance, will the $X_{RMS}(T)$ be significantly different for a pure $\frac{1}{f}$ noise source than for a source with $\frac{1}{f}$ noise for $f$ greater than some $f_{co}$ and a flat response below $f_{co}$, for time windows $T \ll \frac{1}{f_{co}}$?